# What would be a suitable typename for an opengl constant?

Tags: c++, opengl

Currently I am facing a problem when having making a texture function in OpenGL c++. When making a function to use a texture, you would have to bind your texture with an ID and before that you need to set an active texture as shown below:

```
void Texture::UseTexture()
{
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
}
```

in order for the texture class to be more versatile i wish to add an argument to my useTexture() function to have an argument where you could slot in a constant such as GL_TEXTURE0. Are there any typenames that would work or is const enough?

Comment: note that `GL_TEXTURE0` is of type `GLenum`. see: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glActiveTexture.xhtml

Answer (score 1):

The usual way this is done is taking an integer parameter (uint32_t for example) and adding it to `GL_TEXTURE0`:

```
void Texture::UseTexture(uint32_t unit)
{
    if(unit >= MaxTextureUnit) {
         //Handle invalid texture unit
    }
    else {
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + unit);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
    }
}
```

This can be done because the [documentation for glActiveTexture](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es1.1/xhtml/glActiveTexture.xml) states that

> texture must be one of GL_TEXTUREi, where 0 <= i < GL_MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS

and that

> It is always the case that GL_TEXTUREi = GL_TEXTURE0+i .

---

`MaxTextureUnit` is the maximum number of texture units and can be queried with `glGetInteger(GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS, &MaxTextureUnit)`. It's more like a symbolic value here to show how it *could* work, feel free to implement error handling however you like.

Comment: Actually the upper limit is `glGetInteger(GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS, …) `, GL_MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS is just a token to query the actual value.

Comment: @datenwolf Ahh, thanks, I was looking only at the documentation, where they used it like a constant.